# HQL Subquery Problems

Tags: sql, hql

I'm getting a HQL error every time I try to run this subquery. This type of query should work in SQL right? How is HQL handling this type of query differently?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE user_Id IN (
    SELECT a.user_Id
    FROM Table a
    WHERE a.color='Blue')
```

It looks like HQL does not support IN?
I'm getting a error: "Cannot recognize input near 'SELECT'"

Answer (score 1):

In hql if you want to select all fields, you have two ways:

1-You can remove select clause like:

```
 FROM Table
 WHERE user_Id IN (
    SELECT a.user_Id
    FROM Table a
    WHERE a.color='Blue')
```

or

2-If you want to use select clause, you must use an alias:

```
SELECT t
FROM Table t
WHERE t.user_Id IN (
    SELECT a.user_Id
    FROM Table a
WHERE a.color='Blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your syntax is incorrect.  Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE user_Id IN (
    SELECT a.user_Id
    FROM Table a
    WHERE a.color='Blue')
```

Comment: What is the difference here? I could be wrong (and frequently am), but I can't see the difference.

Comment: OP had "FROM a.Table" (before OP editted the question) ... the correct syntax for table alias would be "FROM Table a", which is now in the question.  So, no difference!

Comment: That explains it then!

Answer (score 0):

There is no "*" in HQL. Only alias should be present.

```
SELECT t
FROM Table t
```

HQL supports "In".
Also, make sure, the java class field name is "user_Id". You may be using the DB column name here.